# FreeBSD: Automount to specific location

Tags: freebsd, automounting, autofs

First of all, I read [Vermaden's blog](https://vermaden.wordpress.com/2018/10/11/freebsd-desktop-part-17-automount-removable-media/) which explained a couple different systems used for automounting. I like to use included utilities so I opted for `autofs`. Based on the information in the blog I was able to get that up and running quickly.

The issue I have is that `autofs` is automatically mounting the devices based on the drive label. For example, if I have a USB with a drive label as "BACKUP", it will automount in /media/BACKUP. This means the mount location is constantly changing depending on what USB is being plugged in. I'd like it to mount in a specific location everytime (i.e. /media/usb).

Looking for information I found the [FreeBSD Foundation blog](http://freebsdfoundation.blogspot.com/2015/03/freebsd-from-trenches-using-autofs5-to_13.html). This detailed more of what's going on behind the scenes. The area I'm concerned with was `/etc/autofs/special_media`. This script prints out the label as well as the mount options. This is where I'm lost. It sounds like `automountd` uses the info from `special_media`, but I'm not sure how. Is there a place where I could specify the mount point?

`/etc/autofs/special_media` is a script to print info and doesn't seem right to modify.
`/etc/auto_master` is where you uncomment the special media section. This looks like `fstab` and seems like the likely point where I'd have to modify.
`/etc/devd.conf` is where you add the `autmount -c` call.

Note that I understand that using a single mount location means you can only have one device mounted at a time. Obviously you can't mount two devices to the same location. So I'm expecting the first USB to mount and if any other is plugged in, it would fail to mount.